# What was the original Noahide theology passed from Adam as presented in Job?

Tags: theology, noachide-laws, job-iyov-book-of, noahidism

Rethinking the Book of Job: we're all aware of the 7 Noahide laws. However, beyond the commandments there's a large body of theology, explaining what God is, how He works, and what one should expect from God in his lifetime.

Job was a pious guy, supposedly aware of the Noahide laws - to wit - he was absolutely certain of his blamelessness. It appears that his understanding of God's justness and the direct connection between one's deeds and his reward/punishment is solid.

But where does it come from - was it a part of the Noahide tradition, did he think that alone, or was it a part of Job's gentile culture?

On the other hand, why does God have something new to prove to Job, why doesn't Job already know that God behaves in eccentric and erratic ways?

Comment: https://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/92/Q1/